# How to Show two components for a url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

below is my `app.js` code which will show the components based on the url. when user goes to `/home`, i need to perform some cookie operations. which i'm able to do. Since home component is required for more than one url, every url(`/new,/dashboard`) performs the cookie operation. Is it normal behavior ?

Below is my code, please let me know if this is react way to write it or not. I'm new to react js.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact />
        </Switch>
        
        <Route path="/Home">
           <Home />
           <About />
        </Route>
       
        <Route path="/New">
          <Home />
          <New />
        </Route>
        
        <Route path="/Dashboard">
          <Home />
          <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        
        <Route path="/Run/:testid/">
          <Run>
        </Route>
        
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

below is my home component :

```
import { React, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import "./Home.css";
import useQuery from "../hooks/useQuery";

function Home(props) {

  const q = useQuery();
  console.log(q.get("token"));
  
  //save the token in cookie if url is /home, but since this home component is render for other urls like /new, /dashboard, it gets executed there as well. 

  return (
    <main id="maincontent">
      <div className="dashboard-btns">
        <Link to="/dashboard" className="btn-mobile">
          <Button id="dashboard" buttonStyle="btn--secondary">
            Dashboard
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/new" className="btn-mobile">
          <Button id="new" buttonStyle="btn--secondary">
            New
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <hr className="hr-line" />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

In the **< Home >** component save the token in cookie only if url is `/home`, but since this home component is rendered for other urls like `/new`, `/dashboard`, it gets executed there as well. How do i make it get executed only for `/home` url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Home` component to render on several routes then you can refactor your routes as such, and specify an array of paths for the route rendering `Home`. The `Router` component inclusively matches and render routes, in other words, it renders all matching routes.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact /> // what is this for?
        </Switch>

        <Route path={["/Home", "/New", "/Dashboard"]}>
           <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/Home">
           <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/New">
          <New />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/Dashboard">
          <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        
        <Route path="/Run/:testid/">
          <Run>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Update

> I'm doing some cookie storing and fetching operation in 
> component. But that should happen only on `"/home"` url and shouldn't
> happen on `"/new"`, `"/dashboard"` url. How do I do that?

You can check the current path match and issue a side-effect to do the cookie logic on only the "/home" path.

[useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

> The `useRouteMatch` hook attempts to match the current URL in the same
> way that a `<Route>` would. It’s mostly useful for getting access to the
> match data without actually rendering a `<Route>`.

`match` will be null if path isn't a match, otherwise it will return a [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object.

```
import { React, useEffect } from "react";
...
import { Link, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
...
import useQuery from "../hooks/useQuery";

function Home(props) {
  const q = useQuery();
  console.log(q.get("token"));
  
  const homeMatch = useRouteMatch("/home");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (homeMatch) {
      //save the token in cookie if url is /home and token defined
      const token = q.get("token")
    }
  }, [homeMatch, q]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: @Reese, Thank you for your time. I'm doing some cookie storing and fetching operation in <home> component. But that should happen only on /home url and shouldn't happen on /new, /dashboard url. How do i do that? that was my main ask

Comment: @liquiddeath Oh, I see, I must've missed that part. This is something you can easily check in your `Home` component. Do you mind sharing it in your question?

Comment: @liquiddeath Alternatively, you could factor the cookie logic into a "standalone" component rendered specifically on the "/home" path.

Comment: @Reese, if i render that standalone component in home, since home component is rendered for other url's as well, it will be executed for other urls too right

Comment: @Reese, i have updated the question with home component

Comment: @liquiddeath If you went with an additional standalone route you can restrict it to just "/home" path. I've updated my answer with my first suggestion. If you want to see the second suggestion I can add it as well. Please check out the update.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can use "exact" to prevent that behaviour, Second you should not use two components inside route, what you can do is you can import **Home** inside **New** and **Dashboard** and use it there.

Comment: just importing is enough or do i have to do anything else? can you please explain with an example

Comment: Use `exact` prop to prevent what behavior? Can you be more specific? And there's nothing inherently wrong or incorrect with rendering multiple children in a `Route` component, it's perfectly capable of rendering children.

Comment: @Drew He want to render only specified components in route like /dashboard, but the component mentioned inside / is being rendered too. Yes there is nothing incorrect with rendering multiple childrens, that's why i said you should not instead of you can't.But the proper method is to use only one component in one route.

Comment: @pshrimal000, yes what you said is right, it is one part of the question. second part, i have an operation to do with cookie, that should be done only if url is /home. But the home component is rendered for /new, /dashboard url's, it gets executed there as well. which i don't want to happen.How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLOCE.png)

[markdown.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqHmn.png)

[importing a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIKjf.png)

[using the imported component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDQtz.png)